# Cannot connect to existing database on docker after 2 months

Tags: postgresql, docker, debian

So, as in title I cannot connect to database on docker. I created new container to see where is a problem. On new container everything is working just fine, on old one is a problem. Both of them are created in the same way.

```
d7289b0bb93f   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   0.0.0.0:5544->5432/tcp, :::5544->5432/tcp
bc4118c3356c postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 months ago     Up 14 minutes 0.0.0.0:5437->5432/tcp, :::5437->5432/tcp
```

The one on 5437 just randomly stoped. I use `psql -h localhost -p 5437 -U postgres` and I get following error:

> psql: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5437 failed:
> server closed the connection unexpectedly
>
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while
> processing the request.

When I connect to newly created container `psql -h localhost -p 5544 -U postgres` everything works just fine.

Also the same with ports:

```
> root@:/var/lib/docker/containers# netstat -tunlp | grep 5437
```

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5437            0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN      16161/docker-proxy
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::5437                 :::*                 LISTEN      16167/docker-proxy

```
> root@:/var/lib/docker/containers# netstat -tunlp | grep 5544
```

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5544            0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      16426/docker-proxy
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::5544                 :::*     LISTEN      16434/docker-proxy

Found something strange in logs, I do not understand it tho.

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

 2022-05-30 13:08:27.890 GMT [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
 2022-05-30 13:08:27.891 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
 2022-05-30 13:08:27.891 GMT [1] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Cannot assign requested address
 2022-05-30 13:08:27.893 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
 2022-05-30 13:08:27.899 GMT [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-05-30 13:08:25 GMT
 2022-05-30 13:08:27.904 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 2022-05-30 13:12:43.197 GMT [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
 2022-05-30 13:12:43.198 GMT [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
 2022-05-30 13:12:43.200 GMT [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 32) exited with exit code 1
 2022-05-30 13:12:43.200 GMT [27] LOG:  shutting down
 2022-05-30 13:12:43.210 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Answer (score 0):

So... After I opend container and went to /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf to my shock file was empty. I mean nothing inside... I dunno what the heck happend! Recoverd file, all is good as new.